# breaking a div out of a fixed width div to become 100% wide

Tags: css

at [this page](http://freightplus.com/beta/about-us/), I want the `div.bouble_shaded_bg_full-width` to become 100% the width of the browser.

I have tried the following CSS, but this does not work properly, pushing the div to the side of the page:

```
.bouble_shaded_bg_full-width {
    margin-left: calc(((100%-1140px)/2)*(-1));
    margin-right: calc(((100%-1140px)/2)*(-1));
}
```

where the main content region is 1140px wide.

How do I make `div.bouble_shaded_bg_full-width` 100% of the width of the browser if it is contained inside a fixed width div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below should do it, remove your current right/left margins.

```
.bouble_shaded_bg_full-width {
  width:100vw;
  position:relative;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-50vw;
}
```

Comment: Made that change thanks Lee, but [has made the div around 50% wide and aligned to the left](http://freightplus.com/beta/about-us/).

Comment: Remove the `float:left`

Comment: Done, Lee, issue remains

Comment: You have other `width` values overriding. Check developer tools

Answer (score 0):

Try `100vw`, this will be 100% of the viewport width.

Comment: Thanks virhonestum, but the display remained the same.